# How to sort linkedlist on some natural order?

Tags: java, sorting

We have a linkedlist, the elements of this linkedlist are Employee, I want to sort this linkedlist based on the salary of Employee, salary is one member of Employee Class, can we use Collections.sort()? if not, how can I sort it?
Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Collections.sort()`

You need to have your `Employee` class implement the `Comparable` interface.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

In your `compareTo()` method you would compare the salary of the current object to that of the object passed in.

**Edit:**

The other option you have if you don't want that to be the default comparison is to create a `Comparator` object and use the second form -> `Collections.sort(List, Comparator);`

It would look like this:

```
class SalaryComparator implements Comparator<Employee>
{

    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2)
    {

        if (e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary())
            return 1;
        else if (e1.getSalary() < e2.getSalary())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

Now you can do: `Collections.sort(myEmployeeList, new SalaryComparator());`

Comment: you mean use Collections.sort() and Comparable interface together?

Comment: @ratzip yes, the things in your `Collection` must implement the `Comparable` interface and then whatever `Collection` you put them in can be sorted using `Collections.sort()`.  The `sort()` method will use the `compareTo()` method that is guaranteed by implementing the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Sorry - needed to check that for my own sanity, deleted it for a sec

Comment: Edited to add the other way to go about it.

Comment: `Comparator` is a much better solution here--salary probably isn't the most natural ordering for employees.

Comment: I dunno, it is in a lot of companies I've worked for :-D (Joking aside, I agree)

Comment: How the compareTo() and collections.sort() works together? if the return value is less than 0, then Collections.sort() will exchange these two object? And if the return value is 1 or 0, it does nothing?

Answer (score 4):

While a `LinkedList<Employee>` will work, I'd use an `ArrayList<Employee>` for this:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

After you populate it (either way) you can sort it by salary like so:

```
Collections.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        return e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.sort()`

But in order to do that, your Employee class needs to implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface first.

A rough example would be:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{
    public int compareTo(Employee e)
    {
        return this.salary - e.salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok,I see, but if we implement Comparable interface, there are several sorting Algorithms,like bubble, selection, quick sort and so on, what kind of sorting Algorithms is used by Comparable interface and Collections.sort()?

Comment: The Comparable interface is merely an interface -- it has nothing to do with what algorithm is used by Collections.sort(). Take note that I'm not 100% sure on this but I think Java uses a hybrid merge sort. Rest assured, the time efficiency will be O(nlogn)

Comment: Yup, it uses a modified merge sort, details are in the javadoc for `Collections.sort()`

Comment: I read the tutorial, just want to clarify, implementation of compareTo(), if the return value is less than 0, then Collections.sort() will exchange these two object? And if the return value is 1 or 0, it does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a linked list, but it's not an efficient operation, especially if the list is not trivial in size.  Choose appropriate data structures.

Comment: depends on your data and your usage pattern.  The easy answer is to use arrays, as there are lots of effecient sort algorithms implemented for arrays.  Another answer is to use a B*tree and create your data already sorted.